# suggestion needed for Agora WebSDK

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

Looking for a suggestion,

In a live broadcast show, I also want to record the broadcast so that people can listen to the archived show later. The recoding API, however, does not exist in Web SDK. What would be a good way to record the broadcast?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Agora Cloud Recording RESTFul API. Here is the quick start guide of that: https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/cloud_recording_rest?platform=All%20Platforms. The recorded videos can be stored in a third-party cloud storage like Amazon S3 and Alibaba Cloud.